# No Matching function to call. C++ STL

Tags: c++, function, vector, stl

I'm new to C++ STL. I'm writing a function to check whether one vector is an subset of another(Duplicate elements also count) and print 'Yes' or 'No'. I have come up with the following code :

```
void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazine, vector<string> note) {
    vector<string>::iterator a;
    for(int i=0;i<note.size();i++)
    {
        a=find(magazine.begin(),magazine.end(),note[i]);
        if(a==magazine.end())
        {
            printf("No");
            return;
        }else magazine.erase(a-magazine.begin());
    }
    printf("Yes");
}
```

But,I'm getting the following compilation error :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>
>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*,
std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::difference_type)’
         }else magazine.erase(a-magazine.begin());
```

I'm trying to use erase to delete the found element in magazine.Is there some problem with the type of declaration of the iterator? Why is this happening?
And also if there are alternate methods/logic/inbuilt-functions to get the required job done using STL, Please let me know since I'm new to this and trying to learn it.

Comment: Which one of the [overloaded `erase` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) do you think `magazine.erase(a-magazine.begin())` should call? What do you think `a-magazine.begin()` is evaluated to?

Comment: I thought erase was an inbuilt STL function that can be used to delete an element or range of elements in a vector.

Comment: You're right. But your argument does not specify _"an element or range of elements"_.

Comment: a-magazine.begin() would give the index or position of the found element...Is that wrong?

Comment: No, it is right. But do you see any vector's `erase` function that accepts an index? If you are confused then I would suggest learning about _iterators_. Iterators and indexes are two different concepts.

Comment: My bad,`erase` takes in iterators. So,passing `a` worked...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vivek *I'm trying to use erase to delete the found element in magazine* -- If you're allowed to change those vectors, I suggest you simply `std::sort` both the vectors, and use `std::set_intersection`.  Basically a 3 line solution, and a lot faster if the number of entries are large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erase` takes an iterator. You have that iterator, it's called `a`. But you then convert the iterator `a` into an offset relative to `begin()`. `erase` does not have an overload which takes an offset.

The Standard Library has alternatives if the vectors would be sorted, but we don't see the calling code so we can't assume that.